# Why is a conditional style being set on a html element by Razor is always html encoded incorrectly

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

Using razor to conditionally set a style on a html element always encodes the ' character and renders as &#39 ; (which produces incorrect html and means the browser doesn't render the applied style.

I have tried the following methods:

```
<tr ID="Question-Answer-@(item.QuestionID)" @(!firstItem ? Html.Raw("style=\'display: none\'").ToString() : "" )>   
<tr ID="Question-Answer-@(item.QuestionID)" @(!firstItem ? HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("style=\'display: none\'") : "" )>
<tr ID="Question-Answer-@(item.QuestionID)" @(!firstItem ? "style=\'display: none\'" : "" )>
<tr ID="Question-Answer-@(item.QuestionID)" @(!firstItem ? "style='display: none'" : "")>
<tr ID="Question-Answer-@(item.QuestionID)" @(!firstItem ? new HtmlString("style=\'display: none\'").ToString() : "" )>
```

Both code samples produce the following:

```
<tr ID="Question-Answer-2" style=&#39;display: none&#39;>
and I need:
<tr ID="Question-Answer-2" style='display: none'>
```

Comment: why don't you just `@(!firstItem ? "style=\'display: none\'" : "" )`

Comment: i've just tried that @zgood and it still produces the incorrect output (have updated the Q with your suggestion)

Comment: sorry remove the `\'` and replace with just a single quote `'` ... you don't need to escape that character. You only need to escape it if its a double quote `\"`. Maybe like this: `@(!firstItem ? "style=\"display: none\"" : "" )`

Comment: It still makes no different @zgood, updated Q above accordingly with everything I've tried

Comment: This is actually the answer (but I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question):  `<tr ID="Question-Answer-@(item.QuestionID)" @{if (!firstItem) { <text> style='display: none' </text>  } }>`  @zgood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my question:

```
<tr ID="Question-Answer-@(item.QuestionID)" @{if (!firstItem) { <text> style='display: none' </text> } }>
```

(nb. I still don't understand why the 5 different things I tried above didn't work however)